# Why does CGAL's Delaunay_triangulation_3 return a vertex handle that already exists when it calls insert()?

Tags: c++, cgal

I am trying to build delaunay triangulation inserting points one by one. I've already knew that when inserting a point that already located in the target position will return a vertex handle to that old point. But however, there seem to be other situations where this behavior occurs as well.
I do need different handles for different points in the coordinates, while new added point whose coordinate already exit would not be added and cells may change as point inserting.
And I wonder when and why the return value of `insert()` will be an existing vertex handle.

Here is some key code.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned int, K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<Vb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K, Tds> Triangulation;

typedef K::FT FT;
typedef CGAL::Parallel_if_available_tag Concurrency_tag;

typedef Triangulation::Cell_handle Cell_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Locate_type Locate_type;
typedef Triangulation::Point Point;

class Builder {
public:
    Builder();
    ~Builder();

    void add_points(size_t num_points, float3 *points);
    
private:
    std::unordered_map<size_t, Vertex_handle> idx_to_vertex;
    Triangulation delaunay_tetra;
    unsigned int cur_size = 0;
};
```

And when i implement the function `add_points()` like this

```
void Builder::add_points(size_t num_points, float3 *points) {
    /* add  points sequentially */
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
        auto p = Point(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
        auto vertex_handle = delaunay_tetra.insert(p);
        if (idx_to_vertex.find(vertex_handle->info()) != idx_to_vertex.end()) {
            std::cout << "\033[33m" << "Warning: There is a point already located in the target position (" << points[i].x << ", " << points[i].y << ", " << points[i].z << ")!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        vertex_handle->info() = cur_size;
        idx_to_vertex[cur_size] = vertex_handle;
        cur_size++;
    }
}
```

some points would not be added because the vertex_handle returned by delaunay_tetra.insert(p) has already existed, but its corrdinate seems to be different from any points. And only a little point is recorded but the final `number_of_vertices()` is much more than that.
But when i implemented it without checking like this

```
void TetrahedraBuilder::add_points(size_t num_points, float3 *points) {
    /* add  points sequentially */
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
        auto p = Point(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
        auto vertex_handle = delaunay_tetra.insert(p);
        vertex_handle->info() = cur_size;
        idx_to_vertex[cur_size] = vertex_handle;
        cur_size++;
    }
}
```

the final `number_of_vertices()` is the same as before.
I made more attempts. A function that used to put vertices' coordinates into an array acoording to their indices( the unsigned int info as `typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned int, K> Vb;`) is shown below

```
std::vector<float3> Builder::export_points_idx() {
    std::vector<float3> result(cur_size);
    float *result_float = reinterpret_cast<float*>(result.data());
    size_t cnt = 0;
    for (auto vertex_handle : delaunay_tetra.finite_vertex_handles()) {
        const auto point = vertex_handle->point();
        const unsigned int i = vertex_handle->info();
        result_float[i * 3 + 0] = point.x();
        result_float[i * 3 + 1] = point.y();
        result_float[i * 3 + 2] = point.z();
        cnt += 1;
    }
    std::cout<< "current points number: " << cnt << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

I notice that the length of the list that delaunay_tetra.finite_vertex_handles() returns, not equal to cur_size used to record the number of vertice I added to the delaunay triangulation.
I am totally confused now... Please help me!